# How add object to database use method POST in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, json-server

Expected result: create fake API --> call function `save`--> method POST --> save object `time` to `this.state.resul` --> save db.json todos id 2

I'm using the library `Fake an API with JSON Server`.

**db.json**

```
{
  "todos": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "AAAA"
      "results": [
        {
          "time": "09:10:01",
          "desc": "bbbbb"
        },
        {
          "desc": "gfgfgfgffg",
          "time": "21:30:06"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "BBBBBBB",
      "results": [
        {
          "time": "09:10:01",
          "desc": "reerrererer",
        },
        {
           "desc": "dfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdf",
          "time": "21:30:06"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
```

**Todos**

```
class Todos extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
  super(props);
     this.state = {
     todos: []
   }
 }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/todos")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          todos: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error);
      }
    );
  }

  render () {
     return(
 )      
}
 }
export default Todos;
```

**StopWatch**

```
class StopWatch extends Component {
  constructor() {
   super();

    this.state = {
      resul: []
    };

  }


  save = () => {
     const resul = this.state.resul;
     this.clock = {
      clock: this.clock
    }
    resul.push(this.clock);

    this.setState({
       resul
    });

    axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/todos/2`, {
      results: this.clock
    })
     .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
    });
  }
  }


render () {
   return (
      <ul className="results">


        {
          this.state.resul
            .map((item, index) => 
              <Time 
                key= {index}
              />
            )
        }
      </ul> 
     );
  }
}


export default StopWatch;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `put` to update the array, and pass the whole object you want to update.

```
save = () =>{
  const resul = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.resul));

  this.clock = {
    clock: this.clock
  };
  resul.push(this.clock);

  this.setState({
    resul
  });

  const todo = {
    id: 2,
    title: 'BBBBBBB',
    results: resul
  };

  axios
    .put(`http://localhost:4000/todos/2`, todo)
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```